# Azure SQL Transpose a table with all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I use Azure SQL database. I have a table - test_excel_poc_head with the below values which I want to transpose using link id values as the columns

[image]

The intended output is below where the column is the 'link_id' values. The link_id values are dynamic

[image]

I started using UNPIVOT and PIVOT option and below is my unpivot query and results:

```
SELECT link_id,head_values 
FROM 
(SELECT link_id,comp1,comp2,comp3,comp4
 FROM [dbo].[test_excel_poc_head]
) AS cp
UNPIVOT
(head_values FOR head_value in (comp1,comp2,comp3,comp4)
) AS up
```

RESULTS:

[image]

Now when I add the PIVOT code, it expects an aggregate function which I do not have as it is a string and it errors out.
If I add MAX as the aggregate function, I do not get the intended result.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT link_id,head_values 
FROM 
(SELECT link_id,comp1,comp2,comp3,comp4
 FROM [dbo].[test_excel_poc_head]
) AS cp
UNPIVOT
(head_values FOR head_value in (comp1,comp2,comp3,comp4)
) AS up
) temp_results
PIVOT(
MAX(head_values)
FOR link_id
IN (
[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]
)
) AS PivotTable
```

RESULT:
[image]

But this is not my expected result. Is there any other option to achieve PIVOT without the use of agg functions?
Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried my luck. Could you check below query if it works,

What I did different to your query is making the result of `UNPIVOT` distinct by adding `row_number` to it so that the later `PIVOT` will take max of each row and display separately. My bad if the explanation doesn't makes sense to you.

```
select [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6] 
  from 
  ( select link_id,head_values,
           row_number() over (partition by link_id order by link_id) rn
      from
         ( select link_id
                 ,cast(comp1 as varchar(255)) as comp1
                 ,cast(comp2 as varchar(255)) as comp2
                 ,cast(comp3 as varchar(255)) as comp3
                 ,cast(comp4 as varchar(255)) as comp4
             from [dbo].[test_excel_poc_head]
         ) as cp
    unpivot
    (
      head_values for head_value in (comp1,comp2,comp3,comp4)
    ) as up
   ) temp_results
pivot
(
  max(head_values)
  for link_id in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])
) as pivottable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=984350d373a3a5f396bbcb54dbdaad2f) for your reference.

Comment: I have used additionally cast because the fiddle I used was giving some issue wrt collation and I had to use it to resolve it but you should ignore it in your final query if it works.

Comment: @Suraj, that's nice and you are welcome. Would you mind accepting the answer if it served you the resolution. Thanks.